# emacs flycheck (bash with shellcheck) throws error when using optional characters

Tags: bash, glob, flycheck

I was trying to improve a function definition using flycheck (shellcheck). The commented line on the code below is what I tried to improve. *The code works* but I get the error message `syntax error near unexpected token` ('`

```
my_loop() {
# for ifastq in $(ls $1 | grep -v txt)
for ifastq in $1/*.f?(ast)q?(.gz)
do
echo "$ifastq"
done
}
```

Is the code above more fragile than the one using the commented line?
Should I also include `shopt -s extglob`  in the function definition or at the top of the script?

Thanks

BTW: the code is supposed to capture files with .fastq .fq fq.gz or .fastq.gz extensions

Comment: You can't have spaces before `()` in a function definition.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code. Interestingly, the error was not being flagged and the test code was working with the space

Answer (score 0):

> Is the code above more fragile than the one using the commented line?

No, the opposite. It's generally a bad idea to process the output of `ls`. If any of the filenames contains whitespace, it will be split into multiple words when you use `$(ls ...)`.

You do need to enable `extglob`, since it's not enabled by default.

Extended globbing is a `bash` extension, Flycheck might not recognize it. [Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask questions specific to this Emacs extension.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Should I then, post the question on Emacs SE and delete this one?

Comment: The part specifically about Flycheck seems like it would be appropriate there. But you also asked about the choice of ways to loop, and that fits here.